# Flash Script not loading swf file into stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i wrote a script in ActionScript2.0 to launch an external swf file, but it's giving me an error -

```
  var url:String = "play_button.swf";

  previous_btn.onRelease = function():Void {
       loadMovieNum (url, 0);
 }
```

On running this script, i get an error message saying - 
"Error opening URL 'file:///C|/Users/Chinyere/Desktop/Learning%20Center/Tuts/play_button.swf"

What could be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there's a vertical bar (|) right after C or is that a typographical error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No error there in your script, just make sure your "play_button.swf" is sitting in the "Tuts" folder in the given path.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok, it turns out the url i initially posted wasn't correct.